How to Implement Single Sign-On (SSO) from Timesheet Website to Oracle APEX for Automatic Login?

How can I securely transmit and authenticate the user's session from the timesheet website to Oracle APEX?
2.Which APEX authentication schemes or configuration steps would best support this SSO scenario?
3.Are there any sample implementations or documentation that can guide me in setting up seamless login transitions?

What I've tried: I’ve explored Oracle APEX’s built-in authentication schemes but am not sure how to securely pass user credentials from the timesheet application to Oracle APEX. I’m considering options like cookies or tokens to maintain the session across both applications, but I’d like to know the most secure and efficient approach.
